# Test if PC time is correct in Javascript

Tags: javascript, time

How do I compare the PC time aquired via `new Date()` against a global standard time server to check if the PC time is > 1 hour early/late?

**Edit:** I'm asking for detailed information, and a code snippet if possible. Yes, I know how to compare 2 dates in JS, not asking for help with that.

Answer (score 2):

A recommendation would be http://www.timeanddate.com/services/api/ and as T.J. Crowder said, just compare the two, and output the result.

Comment: Corrected the mistake.